# Replace text \n with actual new line. (C++)

Tags: c++, newline

I'm using C++ and I have a problem. Instead of creating a new line it prints \n. My Code:

`std::string text;`

`std::cout << text;`

It prints:`Hello\nWorld`

It was supposed to read \n as a new line and print something like this:

```
"Hello
World"
```

So i've tried to use `replace(text.begin(), text.end(), '\n', 'a')` for testing purposes and nothing happened. It contiuned to print `Hello\nWorld`

Comment: Escape the new-line character.

Comment: I think we need actual code. You're probably inexperienced, given your question, and it's unclear to me if you're talking about `std::string`, the type, or string literals (a C++ basic language construct) or something else. In `std::cout << "Hello, world \n"` the `\n` is a real newline character,

Comment: If you see `\n` in some output, than the string literal is encoded as `\\n`, and you should replace the substring `"\\n"` with `"\n"`.

Comment: Oh, yes i'm talking about std::string. Sorry.

Comment: I recommend adding a [mre]. Currently your question can only be answered by guesses, and even if the guess is correct, it will be next to useless to the next asker with a similar problem.

Comment: I tested and `replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n', 'a');` works here with this [mcve]: [https://ideone.com/YscMSt](https://ideone.com/YscMSt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) won't work in this situation. When called on a `std::string`, it can replace only single characters, but in your case your string actually contains 2 distinct characters `'\'` and `'n'`.  So you need to use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) instead, eg:

```
string::size_type index = 0;
while ((index = str.find("\\n", index)) != string::npos) {
    str.replace(index, 2, "\n");
    ++index;
}
```